# How to know if an increase is an absolute or a percentage increase

Tags: phrase-usage, usage

How can I know if a sentence is talking about an absolute increase or a percentage increase?

Does this sentence talk about the biggest **percentage** increase because it says "up 9.1 percent"?

> The upscale hotel segment had the biggest increase in revenue per
> room, up 9.1 percent. (The New York Times)

What if I want to talk about an absolute increase. Do I have to use the word "absolute" to let people know that I'm talking about an absolute increase, not a percentage increase?

> The upscale hotel segment had the biggest **absolute** increase in revenue
> per room from $200 to $350. (I wrote it.)

Is "absolute" necessary here?

Comment: https://sciencing.com/difference-between-percent-percentage-point-8409115.html                         https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage_point                                                                                       https://www.mathsisfun.com/percentage-points.html                                                                        https://www.reed.edu/academic_support/pdfs/qskills/percent.pdf

Comment: Surely it's obvious from your use of _either_ percentage points _or_ actual numbers, units of currency or whatever.

Comment: Thank you Kate. Do you mean that my three comments on the answer below are correct?

Answer (score 1):

Our newscasters screw this up all the time. They often mean say "percent" when they mean "percentage points". Here's [an XKCD comic joking about it](https://xkcd.com/985/):

[image: XKCD comic on percentage points]

But in the hotel case, it seems like it must mean actual percent. Percentage points are used when talking about a proportion of something, such as voters who support the candidate in the above comic. But percent is used when discussing a ratio between two numbers. If the price rose from $200 to $218 then it rose by 9 percent, not 9 percentage points.

In the second sentence, "absolute" is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much. In conclusion, you don't say the biggest percentage increase and the biggest absolute increase. You make it clear by the way you add numbers. If you want to mean "percentage increase", then you say "up 9.1 percent": The upscale hotel segment had the biggest increase in revenue per room, up 9.1 percent. If you want to mean "percentage point increase", then you say "up 9.1 percentage point": The upscale hotel segment had the biggest increase in revenue per room, up 9.1 percentage points.

Comment: My last comment is too long. So I started this comment. If you want to mean "absolute increase", you simply add the absolute numbers: The upscale hotel segment had the biggest increase in revenue per room, up $18 dollars. Is this correct?

Comment: Is this the reason why "absolute" in the second sentence of my original post is unnecessary?